# How to efficiently find if numbers in a given range contains either 1 or 3, but not both?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I am having a trouble speeding up my implementation. The question is, given a range of numbers from long a to long b, find how many lucky numbers are between a and b inclusive. A number is a lucky number if it contains either 1 or 3. If it contains both 1 and 3, it is not a lucky number.

Currently, I am iterating over from a to b, inclusive, using for loop, and have a while loop in each iteration where a while loop continues until current number is > 0. In the while loop, I use modulo 10 to get the last digit, check if it's 1 or 3, then set the current number to the number/10.

Is there a way to make this more efficient for range from 10000000000 to 20000000000? With my implementation, it takes around 160 seconds.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = 10000000000L;
        long end = 20000000000L;

        int total = 0;

        double startTime = System.nanoTime();

        for (long i = start;i <= end; i++) {
            int numOf1 = 0;
            int numOf3 = 0;
            long number = i;
            while (number > 0) {
                long lastDigit = number % 10;
                if (lastDigit == 1) {
                    numOf1++;
                } else if (lastDigit == 3) {
                    numOf3++;
                }

                if (numOf1 > 0 && numOf3 > 0) {
                    break;
                }
                number /= 10;
            }

            if (numOf1 > 0 || numOf3 > 0) {
                total++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(total);
        double endTime = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println((endTime - startTime) / 1000000000);


    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. The title of your question is slightly misleading from the task you described in your post,  please modify it to make it more inherent to the problem.

Comment: If I am not toally mistaken, there's a bug: if you find at least one 1 *and* at least one 3, you break the inner loop, as (numOf1 > 0 && numOf3 > 0). Then, in the outer loop, (numOf1 > 0 || numOf3 > 0) is also true (as both are > 0) and thus you count the number as a lucky number, which is wrong according to the problem statement.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug. Also, I edited the title, sorry about that.

Comment: Is this an interview question?  Then asking here might not be a good idea.

Comment: It is similar to one of the questions I got on online technical assessment and I was already done with it when I posted the question. I was just curious of a solution that can solve a larger range in 3 seconds because I didn't pass that test case and I wanted to find out. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 3):

## A Bug

> ```
> if (numOf1 > 0 || numOf3 > 0) {
>     total++;
> }
> ```

That overcounts. The definition of "lucky number" included "if it contains both 1 and 3, it is not a lucky number", but numbers that contain both a 1 and a 3 *are* counted. The `break` in the `while`-loop exits that loop when that condition is detected, but then the code above still runs. You could use:

```
if ((numOf1 > 0) != (numOf3 > 0)) {
    total++;
}
```

The `!=` between two booleans is a slightly tricky way to say "one of them but not both". Of course that can be written out more explicitly.

## An other bug

> ```
> int total = 0;
> ```

Do you know how big the result is? By my count it's just over 3.48 billion. That's a problem, `int` only goes just over 2.14 billion. The count doesn't go over 4.29 billion, so you *could* still use `int`, and then interpret it as an unsigned integer later (eg printing `total & 0xFFFFFFFFL`). But that's strange, a bit advanced, not for beginners. Using `long total = 0;` is a simpler and more sensible solution.

> **Is there a way to make this more efficient for range from 10000000000 to 20000000000?**

There are some specific properties of that range that you could use.

First, let's ignore 20000000000 itself, it contains neither a `1` nor a `3`.

Then, every number in the range for sure has at least one `1` in it, so you don't need to test it, this is something you already know. That would let you simplify the test to "check if there is any `3` in the number".

## Counting without brute force

Forgetting the leading 1, the numbers in our range have 10 "variable" digits.
How many 10-digit strings of digits 0..9 *don't* have a 3 in them? Every place has 9 possible digits left instead of 10, so rather than `pow(10, 10)` it will be `pow(9, 10)`.

`pow(9, 10)` is something that you can calculate easily, even with just `Math.pow(9, 10)`. It's normally not really proper to use `double`s for integer calculations, but this one works.

> **With my implementation, it takes around 160 seconds.**

Does it actually? That's an order of magnitude faster than it runs on my PC.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bugs. Sorry to ask again, but if I am trying to calculate between the range from 59 to 5203987742 for example, how can that be calculated without brute force? Also, when I ran the code again after fixing the bugs, it gave me 4826085154 lucky numbers between 10000000000 and 20000000000, but pow(9, 10) should give 3486784401. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JuhyeonLee I'll add something about different ranges later. I'm not sure what that other trouble is, if I test it for 100000000 to 200000000 (less range, to make it faster), it all comes out fine. Besides, as far as I can tell, the math checks out.

Comment: Thank you. That will be really helpful. And when I test for 100000000 to 200000000, it comes out as 52539010. Is that the number you got?

Comment: @JuhyeonLee I get 43046721 (with both implementations)

Comment: I got the right number for 100000000-200000000 and 10000000000-20000000000. I was trying with different digits like 4 and 8 instead of 1 and 3 for lucky numbers. After changing back to 1 and 3, it worked fine. If you have a time later, any idea on how to calculate between 2 random ranges like 29382938-84720398 would be very helpful! Thank you.

Comment: @JuhyeonLee OK sorry I changed my mind, different ranges are too annoying for me to work out, you do something recursive

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Say you are at a number *abcdef*. If b==1 and d==3 you can skip from *abcd00* to *abc(d+1)00*. That is the gist of optimizing the algorithm.

Needing the individual digits and intelligently stepping to the next digits seems a better approach. (Now decomposing *every* number in digits.)

Use an array of digits, and compose the lucky numbers.

As far as a **review** of the existing code goes, is the review from **@harold** fine.

---

***Clarification, schematic solution:***

Your code walks *all* numbers and for every number looks at its digits:

```
// Loop for every number i:
for (long i = start; i <= end; i++) {

    // Loop to determine all digits again:
    long number = i;
    while (number > 0) {
        long lastDigit = number % 10; ...
        number /= 10;
    }
```

It would be better to have the digits as array or char array/StringBuilder (the inner loop):

If you store the digits with the least significant first 1234 as {4, 3, 2, 1}
then you use for loops with ++.

```
int[] startDigits = ...
int[] endDigits = ...
assert startDigits.length == endDigits.length;

int[] digits = startDigits();
while (!Arrays.equals(digits, endDigits); stepNext(digits)) {
    int p1 = digits.indexOf(1);
    int p3 = digits.indexOf(3);
    if ((p1 >= 0) != (p3 >= 0) {
        // Lucky
        print number ... a[2] a[1] a[0]
    } else {
        int p = Math.min(p1, p3);
        for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
            a[i] = 9;
        }
    }
    // increment digits from a[0] .. a[n-1]
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        boolean carry = a[i] == 9;
        if (carry) {
            a[i] = 0;
        } else {
            ++a[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above shows one shortcut for having an unlucky number with first position of 1 or 3 at p. There are other possibilities too.

---

***An abstract solution of the problem:***

A lucky number looks a bit like `abc...X...def` where X is 1 or 3, and a, b, c, d, e, f are not Y (3 or 1) - but may be X.

How many different combinations are there? And then from start to end?

For N digits with n Xs you need the number of possible combinations (math) (times 2 for X in  {1, 3}) and the other digits can each have 8 values (not 1 or 3). In fact this subproblem is like counting the number of 1s/0s in a binary number of N bits: 10000, 11000, 10100, ... - There are 2^N - 1 different combinations with at one 1. 00000 being the exception. If 1 represents X,
the number with 3 0s would be N over 3 which would add 2*8^(N over 3) = (1 or 3)*(8 candidates for the N-3 0s).

Start and end restrictions are the difficult part. Simplify by excluding the common prefix. And then you need to walk the actual patterns 1101001 and check which digits are allowed there.

To exclude 000 == without 1, and get all bit patterns:

```
long luckyNumbers = 0;
assert N < 64;
for (long bitPattern = 1; bitPattern < (1L << N); ++bitPattern) {
     // Check the possible number of digits for every bit.
     ...
```

This reduces the problem merely from N digits to N bits, but you have only lucky numbers and need not create all 10^N numbers.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I am sorry, but I do not fully understand the logic where you said to use an array of digits. Could you please explain in more detail if that's fine with you?

Comment: Thank you for explaining more in detail! I will try to understand the code!

Comment: Thank you for the abstract solution of the problem. If you can have multiple 1s or 3s in a number, would that change the solution?

Comment: Lucky numbers are multiple of either 1s or 3s and the other digits _not 3 or 1_. Hence you can use a bit pattern 0010010 for here two 3s or two 1s and five other chars: the count of lucky numbers would be 2*8^5 , the factor 2 for 1 or 3, 8 for the remaining 8 digits and 5 for the 0-positions. So yes. Be aware that a solution is not that easy as the filled in ten digits must form a number between start and end.